# Javascript making a statement dynamic

Tags: javascript

I have an variable idx2 which is equal 10 and want to uses it in dynamic situation with an object:   "abc.abc**10**.test();"  i want to replace 10 with "idx2"  so it should look like  "abc.abc**idx2**.test()" to make the statement  dynamic and not hard coded.   I am not sure how to word the question to search for it in javascript and how correctly to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
object.field      and
object['field']
```

are two ways of accessing the same thing.

So instead of using:

```
abc.abc10
```

you can use

```
abc['abc10']
```

so what you want is

```
abc['abc' + idx2]
```

for example:

```
abc['abc' + idx2].test();
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose your object is

```
var obj = {
  "A_idx2": { test: function(){ console.log( 1 ); } } },
  "A_idx4": { test: function(){ console.log( 413 ); } },
  "A_idx5": { test: function(){ console.log( 551 ); } },
}
var a = "idx2";
obj[ "A_" + a ].test(); //outputs 1
a = "idx4";
obj[ "A_" + a ].test(); //outputs 413
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly and i kind of understood it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're after is bracket notation:

`abc.abc[idx2].test();`

Comment: i beleave you mean [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) :-)

Comment: @Grundy Right you are. :)

Comment: i dont think i want abc[10] i need abc10 or abcXX  by subbing out XX with idx2 with what ever value it has

Answer (score 0):

call it using

```
window[Dynamic funtion name](arg1, arg2,...);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use eval function to run string as a statement.

```
var dynamical = "idx2";

var statement = "abc.abc" + dynamical + ".test()"

eval(statement);
```